# My API on heroku sends JSON as plain text in the response instead of sending the JSON itself

Tags: json, python-3.x, heroku, gunicorn, flask-restful

I made a REST API in python using flask-RESTful, to run it locally I can use flask and it works fine, but to deploy on heroku I have to use gunicorn, the problem is that gunicorn sents the json as plain text and it is ugly, I use gunicorn because i cant use flask by itself, It fails to work on vanilla heroku and also there are no guides that actually use flask without gunicorn on heroku.

PS[1]: I dont specify an ip address in flask or gunicorn, i let it decide by itself.

PS[2]: my api link on heroku using gunicorn: https://arjixgamersapi.herokuapp.com/

[Local JSON image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGLvJ.png)

[Deployed JSON image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMbxO.png)

Answer (score 0):

For sending Json formatted responses in Flask I used to use the jsonify() function from the flask package.
"It creates a Response with the JSON representation of the given arguments with an application/json mimetype" (https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.jsonify)

Comment: Thank you for your sincere answer but the problem isn't what i send as a response, the problem lies with gunicorn that sends the response as plain text, I already use the jsonify function in my code.